# Why do NSwag fail on my computer and not on my colleagues for the same C# project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, openapi, nswag

I'm working on a large C# Asp.NetCore 3.1 project where we uses **Nswag** to generate swagger.json and a C# ProxyClient for our API.
Suddenly I cannot generate any of these files for this project anymore, as **NSwag** fails with a "No service for type" as seen below.

I've tried to Git clone a new version of the solution, to a fresh folder on my machine, but he problem persists.
When my colleagues do the same on their machines, they do not have the problem, thus we concluded that it has nothing to do with our code.

I've created a small Asp.NetCore 3.1 API and added the "openapi.nswag" file we use in the original project. I'm not experiencing the issue with this solution, so I havn't been able to reproduce the error.

I've tried everything that comes in to my mind:
updated NSwag to newest version, restarted my Computer, removed Nswag and reinstalled it, cleaned up the registry for anything related to Nswag, tried creating the files using NSwagStudio.

I'm really running out of ideas here, so any help would be appreciated.

```
.\nswag run ..\..\openapi.nswag /runtime:NetCore31

NSwag command line tool for .NET Core NetCore31, toolchain v13.7.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.24.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))
Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
NSwag bin directory: C:\Source\MyProgram\src\B2B\B2B.API\node_modules\nswag\bin\binaries\NetCore31

Executing file '..\..\openapi.nswag' with variables ''...
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderFactory<>[Autofac.ContainerBuilder]' has been registered.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder<>.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ConfigureServices>g__ConfigureServicesWithContainerConfiguration|0(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.Initialize()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
> at NSwag.Commands.Generation.OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase<>.CreateWebHostAsync(AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\OpenApiGeneratorCommandBase.cs:line 342
> at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunIsolatedAsync(AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 310
> at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase<>.IsolatedCommandAssemblyLoader<>.Run(String commandType, String commandData, String[] assemblyPaths, String[] referencePaths) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedCommandBase.cs:line 76
> at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase<>.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<RunIsolatedAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedCommandBase.cs:line 61
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task<>.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedCommandBase<>.RunIsolatedAsync(String configurationFile) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedCommandBase.cs:line 61
> at NSwag.Commands.IsolatedSwaggerOutputCommandBase<>.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\IsolatedSwaggerOutputCommandBase.cs:line 51
> at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Generation\AspNetCore\AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 95
> at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 280
> at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagDocument.cs:line 81
> at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Document\ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 86
> at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\Commands\Document\ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 32
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
> at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.Process(String[] args, Object input)
> at NSwag.Commands.NSwagCommandProcessor.Process(String[] args) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.Commands\NSwagCommandProcessor.cs:line 56child_process.js:669
> throw err;

Comment: The error suggests you're not able to run the code at all. Are you dynamic loading DLL's on runtime by using `Assembly.Load(..)`? Because the error is pretty clear: you did not register a type with Autofac `System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderFactory<>[Autofac.ContainerBuilder]' has been registered.`

Comment: The code builds and executes as expected. It’s the exact same code as on my colleagues computer.

Comment: Hmmm.. the type is `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderFactory` which is typically part of the framework. Do you have the same components/frameworks installed?

Comment: Yes... it’s exactly the same

Answer (score 3):

Finally after cloning NSwag and debugging it, I found the problem.

NSwag is looking for the *program* class in the assembly you want's to create a proxyclient for. It does that by refelction and then NSwag invokes it.
Fortunally if *program* throws an exception it is surpressed by NSwag and it then runs a "fallback routin" where it instead creates the Webhost itself, by using the *startup* class from the Assembly. When doing this the Webhost wasn't created with *AutofacServiceProviderFactory* as ServiceProviderFactory, thus throwing the exception above instead of initial exeption.

In my case the problem was that the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable was not set, so it wouldn't read then correct settings.
My colleauges had this environment variable set globally, but I didn't.
It turned out that this setting can be set as a part of the .nswag configuration

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me to address issue with `DI` services not resolving right for `NSwag` `MSBuild` target I described here [#3737: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider' has been registered](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/3737)